# Android R : starting default launch activity not working

Tags: android

I have this code to start the default launch activity (it's in a module, common to different related apps), which is working fine with Android 10, 9, 8, ...

```
private synchronized void goToLaunchActivity() {
    if (!isFinishing()) {
        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName());
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Now I tested it with Android 11 Beta and the launch activity is not started. There is no error or warning to be seen in Logcat, so I have no idea why this is not working.

Comment: Android 11 is a beta, in the beta 1 I had problems related to activity life cycle. With beta 2 everything is fixed by them. I didn't touch anything. I suggest you to wait for the next beta.

Comment: @gcantoni Thanks, I know its a beta, we want to prepare our apps in advance. Didn't know about them having life cylce issues. I think it is more related to package-manager, since I changed our code to inject a concrete intent, and that is working.